# PHPUnit Selenium2Testcase not working with data provider

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following PHP unit test case.

For checking purposes I commented out the actual test (even with the `->url()` call it does not work)

```
<?php

class BasicTest extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase
{
    static $browsers = array(
        'chrome28win7' =>
            array(
                'browserName' => 'chrome',
                'desiredCapabilities' => array(
                    'version' => '28',
                    'os' => 'Windows',
                    'os_version' => '7',
                    'resolution' => '1280x1024',
                ),
            ),

    );

    /**
     * @dataProvider urlDataProvider
     * @param $path
     */
    public function testUrlScreenshot($path)
    {
        return; // for checking
        $this->url(env('BROWSER_BASE') . $path);
    }

    public static function urlDataProvider()
    {
        $list = <<<EOL
datenschutz.html
impressum.html
EOL;
        $plainArray = explode("\n", $list);

        $result = array();

        foreach($plainArray as $entry) {
            $result = array($entry);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
/usr/bin/php /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit --configuration /home/example/local-workspace/example/phpunit.xml --filter "/::testUrlScreenshot( .*)?$/" BasicTest /home/example/local-workspace/example/tests/frontend/BasicTest.php --teamcity
Testing started at 10:18 ...
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPUnit_Framework_WarningTestCase::setupSpecificBrowser() in /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumBrowserSuite.php on line 95
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:47
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:110
PHP   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:133
PHP   5. ReflectionMethod->invoke() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:87
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase::suite() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:87
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestSuite::fromTestCaseClass() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/Selenium2TestCase.php:371
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumBrowserSuite->setupSpecificBrowser() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestSuite.php:142
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumBrowserSuite->browserOnAllTests() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumBrowserSuite.php:86
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumBrowserSuite->browserOnAllTests() /home/example/local-workspace/example/vendor/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumBrowserSuite.php:93
```

if I do not use the dataProvider annotation, I can run tests. Why is that? Is `@dataProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception actually covered up another error.

Debugging revealed this:

[image]

So PHP Unit raised an error because my dataset was invalid (dataset needs to be an array of arrays), which somehow made PHPUnit trying to call `setupSpecificBrowser()` on the exception class.

Fixing the dataset fixed the error.